# PHP file in Docker/PHP5/Apache is outputting source code, not executing PHP

Tags: php, apache, docker

I'm trying to Dockerize a legacy php application however apache is just outputting the PHP source code and not either executing the PHP code at the top or outputting the HTML underneath.  As I say, it's a legacy app and the structure is as follows:

```
<?php
  some php code;
?>
<html>
  some html
</html>
```

I'm sure I've got things connected as a simple

```
<?php
  print phpinfo();
?>
```

works fine and outputs phpinfo() as expected.

Is there some limitation or something I've overlooked?

Dockerfile is

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
```

docker-compose.yml is as follows:

```
version: '2'    
services:
        webserver:
                build: ./
                image: runwaytest_web
                ports:
                        - "2020:80"
                        - "2043:443"
                volumes:
                        - /Users/me/dev/project/www:/var/www/html
```

Comment: What's different between the example that is parsed and the one that is not? Check the file extensions.

Comment: Check for short tags `<?` also.

Comment: It sounds like your php files are being loaded as text files which means PHP is not running.   I believe your docker build file needs you to include something that tells it to run php.

Comment: Try this: http://markusos.github.io/projects/2015/07/21/dockerizing-a-php-project.html

Comment: No worries, cleaned up some whitespace in the file (spare empty lines) and it started working.  No idea why my native OS was happy with it but apache/php in docker wasn't..

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Some empty lines were causing docker/php/apache to fail but my native OS was happy with it. Go figure..